# Find the number of quadruplets with GCD equal to 1

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

Given a sequence of numbers from 1 to N, we have to find the number of quadruplets such that their Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) is 1.

*Constraints* : N <= 10^5

*Example* : N=5. So the number of such quadruplets from {1,2,3,4,5} are :

- {1,2,3,4}
- {1,2,3,5}
- {1,2,4,5}
- {1,3,4,5}
- {2,3,4,5}

So the answer in this case is 5.

Comment: What do you mean by 'assign different powers of each prime'?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I did try to code using the approaches in the answer but I found glitches in them. You can see my code here : https://pastebin.com/2cap5HCs.
Appreciate and totally align with your concern. 
Since you have the algorithm, would you mind sharing it.

Comment: I don't understand what's the issue with the question. This was a subproblem I was stuck at and hoped for help. This community offers a lot of unnecessary backlash sometimes.

Comment: When you first asked the question, you showed absolutely no work or code of your own. Even now you do not show that work in your question--you put a link to your code in a comment. There are too many people who just try to dump their work on others on this site and there is a backlash here against such people. You appeared to be one of those people. In your future questions, be more quick to visibly follow the rules of this site and you will get much good help here. But asking a good question takes work--do the work, do it visibly, and do it in  your first version of your question.

Comment: By the way, I have answered your question with an algorithm and code and voted to reopen it. If you edit your question to show your code, I will upvote your question. There are still things you can do to get better treatment and more help on this site. We would like you to stay here, but you do need to work  a little more on your questions.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I will surely work on this aspect. Found your feedback valuable.

Answer (score 1):

We will solve this problem in reverse order.
If we have n numbers, way of selecting 4 from n is nC4.
Now if we know the ways of selecting 4 from n such that gcd of selected 4 numbers are greater than 1, than we can easily get our expected result.

So if the number of quadrants is m such that gcd of each quadrant is >1 , our expected result will be nc4-m.

So how can we know the number of quadrant such that gcd of each quadrant is greater than 1.

factor.

Now factorize i:

Let,
   prime factor of i is A^3*B^2*C^3.
   So distinct prime factor is A,B,C.

Now we will consider each A,B,C one by one.

Total numbers which are devided by A is X=(i-1)/A, We can select 3 by XC3 ways.
Total numbers which are devided by B is Y=(i-1)/A, We can select 3 by YC3 ways.
Total numbers which are devided by C is Z=(i-1)/A, We can select 3 by ZC3 ways.

But problem is some numbers which are devided by A can be devided by B.
For example, AB is devided by A as well as B.
So by this approach we will have duplicate qudrant.

So solve this problem we will generate all possible subset of the distinct prime and  we will use exclusion and inclusion approach.

Inclusion exclusion formula:

number of total set of qudrant = number of qudrant devided by A + number of qudrant devided by B
number of qudrant devided by C-number of qudrant devided by AB-number of qudrant devided by BC -number of qudrant devided by CA + number of qudrant devided by ABC.

**General formula :**

[image: exclusion inclusion]

By this approach we will get the total number of qudrant for each i such that gcd of each qudrant will be greater than 1.

So now we have the number of quadrant (m) where each quadrant have  gcd greater than 1.

So  our final result will be nC4-m.

**Complexity:**

Complexity to found the prime factor of each number from 4 to n is O(nlogn)

for each i we will get at most 7 distinct prime . So we will have 2^7 subset.
So total complexity will be (nlogn+n*2^7*7).

**I have added code link on comment.**

Comment: The algorithm is slightly incorrect. What about the case when say we select all 3 as non coprimes to th i'th number, but they make a gdc of 1 within themselves thereby making the net gcd of the quadruplet 1. For eg. say the i'th number is 6. Coprimes: {1,5}, Non-coPrimes: {2,3,4}. The algo mentioned by you wouldn't cover the quadruplet {2,3,4,6}.

Comment: Finding the Euler Totient function for a given number is not very quick--I believe it is close to linear in execution time. So your overall algorithm seems like it would be quadratic in `N`. That is faster than the brute-force method but still pretty slow. Could you find a modification that would speed up your algorithm?

Comment: Finding euler totient for 1 to n number i's possible with O(nlogn) complexity. Actually  with seive it i's possible to find the euler totient.

Comment: The approach still wouldn' t give the correct results. What you aren't focusing on is that, even if we select 3 numbers which are non-coprime to the i'th number, any 2 of those 3 maybe coprime which will make the GCD of the quadruplet as 1.

Comment: @TejasSardana Hope it will works now.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Wj4Z9gqY

Comment: Why do you write that you will get at most 7 prime numbers? You can get at most 6 primes to have a product below `10^5` (`2*3*5*7*11*13`). And you can get at most 5 to have a product below `10^5/4`, which is what is needed in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have shown some code of your own, I'll provide an algorithm and Python 3 code.

We will emphasize the number of quadruplets that have a GCD *greater than 1*. For example, if the GCD is `2`, then all four numbers are divisible by `2`. How many quadruplets have all numbers divisible by `2`? There are `N // 2` numbers in the domain `1` through `N` that are divisible by `2`, so there are `(N // 2) choose 4` such quadruplets. Similarly, there are `(N // 3) choose 4` quadruplets where all the numbers are divisible by `3`. We do not need to look at those divisible by `4` since they are already divisible by `2` and we have already counted them. The largest prime number that can divide all four numbers is at most `N // 4` since we need four different numbers in the combination divisible by that largest number.

So it seems that we look at all prime numbers from `2` to `N // 4` and count the combinations. However, what about the combinations divisible by `6`? We double-counted those, since they are divisible by both `2` and `3`. But we can un-count them by subracting their count, rather than adding the counts as we did for `2` and `3`.

This is a brief introduction to [the inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). In summary, we take all combinations of distinct prime numbers whose product is not greater than `N // 4`. There are then `N // product` numbers that may be in a quadruplet that are divisible by that `product`. We calculate `(N // product) choose 4`, which is the count of the quadruplets where all those values are divisible by all those primes. We add that count if there were an even number of primes and subtract if there were an odd number of primes. We get the full count of all combinations of four numbers by looking at the "empty combination" containing no primes. We add that, then subtract combinations for one prime number, add combinations for two distinct primes, subtract combinations for three distinct primes, etc.

Here is my Python 3 code. To keep things simple and since I often program with prime numbers, I store a moderate-sized list of the first prime numbers. In your problem you need the primes up to `25000`. You could do this differently if you like, by calculating that list once at the start of your routine, but here is my list.

```
primes_2_25000 = [
      2,     3,     5,     7,    11,    13,    17,    19,    23,    29,
     31,    37,    41,    43,    47,    53,    59,    61,    67,    71,
     73,    79,    83,    89,    97,   101,   103,   107,   109,   113,
    127,   131,   137,   139,   149,   151,   157,   163,   167,   173,
    179,   181,   191,   193,   197,   199,   211,   223,   227,   229,
    233,   239,   241,   251,   257,   263,   269,   271,   277,   281,
    283,   293,   307,   311,   313,   317,   331,   337,   347,   349,
    353,   359,   367,   373,   379,   383,   389,   397,   401,   409,
    419,   421,   431,   433,   439,   443,   449,   457,   461,   463,
    467,   479,   487,   491,   499,   503,   509,   521,   523,   541,
    547,   557,   563,   569,   571,   577,   587,   593,   599,   601,
    607,   613,   617,   619,   631,   641,   643,   647,   653,   659,
    661,   673,   677,   683,   691,   701,   709,   719,   727,   733,
    739,   743,   751,   757,   761,   769,   773,   787,   797,   809,
    811,   821,   823,   827,   829,   839,   853,   857,   859,   863,
    877,   881,   883,   887,   907,   911,   919,   929,   937,   941,
    947,   953,   967,   971,   977,   983,   991,   997,  1009,  1013,
   1019,  1021,  1031,  1033,  1039,  1049,  1051,  1061,  1063,  1069,
   1087,  1091,  1093,  1097,  1103,  1109,  1117,  1123,  1129,  1151,
   1153,  1163,  1171,  1181,  1187,  1193,  1201,  1213,  1217,  1223,
   1229,  1231,  1237,  1249,  1259,  1277,  1279,  1283,  1289,  1291,
   1297,  1301,  1303,  1307,  1319,  1321,  1327,  1361,  1367,  1373,
   1381,  1399,  1409,  1423,  1427,  1429,  1433,  1439,  1447,  1451,
   1453,  1459,  1471,  1481,  1483,  1487,  1489,  1493,  1499,  1511,
   1523,  1531,  1543,  1549,  1553,  1559,  1567,  1571,  1579,  1583,
   1597,  1601,  1607,  1609,  1613,  1619,  1621,  1627,  1637,  1657,
   1663,  1667,  1669,  1693,  1697,  1699,  1709,  1721,  1723,  1733,
   1741,  1747,  1753,  1759,  1777,  1783,  1787,  1789,  1801,  1811,
   1823,  1831,  1847,  1861,  1867,  1871,  1873,  1877,  1879,  1889,
   1901,  1907,  1913,  1931,  1933,  1949,  1951,  1973,  1979,  1987,
   1993,  1997,  1999,  2003,  2011,  2017,  2027,  2029,  2039,  2053,
   2063,  2069,  2081,  2083,  2087,  2089,  2099,  2111,  2113,  2129,
   2131,  2137,  2141,  2143,  2153,  2161,  2179,  2203,  2207,  2213,
   2221,  2237,  2239,  2243,  2251,  2267,  2269,  2273,  2281,  2287,
   2293,  2297,  2309,  2311,  2333,  2339,  2341,  2347,  2351,  2357,
   2371,  2377,  2381,  2383,  2389,  2393,  2399,  2411,  2417,  2423,
   2437,  2441,  2447,  2459,  2467,  2473,  2477,  2503,  2521,  2531,
   2539,  2543,  2549,  2551,  2557,  2579,  2591,  2593,  2609,  2617,
   2621,  2633,  2647,  2657,  2659,  2663,  2671,  2677,  2683,  2687,
   2689,  2693,  2699,  2707,  2711,  2713,  2719,  2729,  2731,  2741,
   2749,  2753,  2767,  2777,  2789,  2791,  2797,  2801,  2803,  2819,
   2833,  2837,  2843,  2851,  2857,  2861,  2879,  2887,  2897,  2903,
   2909,  2917,  2927,  2939,  2953,  2957,  2963,  2969,  2971,  2999,
   3001,  3011,  3019,  3023,  3037,  3041,  3049,  3061,  3067,  3079,
   3083,  3089,  3109,  3119,  3121,  3137,  3163,  3167,  3169,  3181,
   3187,  3191,  3203,  3209,  3217,  3221,  3229,  3251,  3253,  3257,
   3259,  3271,  3299,  3301,  3307,  3313,  3319,  3323,  3329,  3331,
   3343,  3347,  3359,  3361,  3371,  3373,  3389,  3391,  3407,  3413,
   3433,  3449,  3457,  3461,  3463,  3467,  3469,  3491,  3499,  3511,
   3517,  3527,  3529,  3533,  3539,  3541,  3547,  3557,  3559,  3571,
   3581,  3583,  3593,  3607,  3613,  3617,  3623,  3631,  3637,  3643,
   3659,  3671,  3673,  3677,  3691,  3697,  3701,  3709,  3719,  3727,
   3733,  3739,  3761,  3767,  3769,  3779,  3793,  3797,  3803,  3821,
   3823,  3833,  3847,  3851,  3853,  3863,  3877,  3881,  3889,  3907,
   3911,  3917,  3919,  3923,  3929,  3931,  3943,  3947,  3967,  3989,
   4001,  4003,  4007,  4013,  4019,  4021,  4027,  4049,  4051,  4057,
   4073,  4079,  4091,  4093,  4099,  4111,  4127,  4129,  4133,  4139,
   4153,  4157,  4159,  4177,  4201,  4211,  4217,  4219,  4229,  4231,
   4241,  4243,  4253,  4259,  4261,  4271,  4273,  4283,  4289,  4297,
   4327,  4337,  4339,  4349,  4357,  4363,  4373,  4391,  4397,  4409,
   4421,  4423,  4441,  4447,  4451,  4457,  4463,  4481,  4483,  4493,
   4507,  4513,  4517,  4519,  4523,  4547,  4549,  4561,  4567,  4583,
   4591,  4597,  4603,  4621,  4637,  4639,  4643,  4649,  4651,  4657,
   4663,  4673,  4679,  4691,  4703,  4721,  4723,  4729,  4733,  4751,
   4759,  4783,  4787,  4789,  4793,  4799,  4801,  4813,  4817,  4831,
   4861,  4871,  4877,  4889,  4903,  4909,  4919,  4931,  4933,  4937,
   4943,  4951,  4957,  4967,  4969,  4973,  4987,  4993,  4999,  5003,
   5009,  5011,  5021,  5023,  5039,  5051,  5059,  5077,  5081,  5087,
   5099,  5101,  5107,  5113,  5119,  5147,  5153,  5167,  5171,  5179,
   5189,  5197,  5209,  5227,  5231,  5233,  5237,  5261,  5273,  5279,
   5281,  5297,  5303,  5309,  5323,  5333,  5347,  5351,  5381,  5387,
   5393,  5399,  5407,  5413,  5417,  5419,  5431,  5437,  5441,  5443,
   5449,  5471,  5477,  5479,  5483,  5501,  5503,  5507,  5519,  5521,
   5527,  5531,  5557,  5563,  5569,  5573,  5581,  5591,  5623,  5639,
   5641,  5647,  5651,  5653,  5657,  5659,  5669,  5683,  5689,  5693,
   5701,  5711,  5717,  5737,  5741,  5743,  5749,  5779,  5783,  5791,
   5801,  5807,  5813,  5821,  5827,  5839,  5843,  5849,  5851,  5857,
   5861,  5867,  5869,  5879,  5881,  5897,  5903,  5923,  5927,  5939,
   5953,  5981,  5987,  6007,  6011,  6029,  6037,  6043,  6047,  6053,
   6067,  6073,  6079,  6089,  6091,  6101,  6113,  6121,  6131,  6133,
   6143,  6151,  6163,  6173,  6197,  6199,  6203,  6211,  6217,  6221,
   6229,  6247,  6257,  6263,  6269,  6271,  6277,  6287,  6299,  6301,
   6311,  6317,  6323,  6329,  6337,  6343,  6353,  6359,  6361,  6367,
   6373,  6379,  6389,  6397,  6421,  6427,  6449,  6451,  6469,  6473,
   6481,  6491,  6521,  6529,  6547,  6551,  6553,  6563,  6569,  6571,
   6577,  6581,  6599,  6607,  6619,  6637,  6653,  6659,  6661,  6673,
   6679,  6689,  6691,  6701,  6703,  6709,  6719,  6733,  6737,  6761,
   6763,  6779,  6781,  6791,  6793,  6803,  6823,  6827,  6829,  6833,
   6841,  6857,  6863,  6869,  6871,  6883,  6899,  6907,  6911,  6917,
   6947,  6949,  6959,  6961,  6967,  6971,  6977,  6983,  6991,  6997,
   7001,  7013,  7019,  7027,  7039,  7043,  7057,  7069,  7079,  7103,
   7109,  7121,  7127,  7129,  7151,  7159,  7177,  7187,  7193,  7207,
   7211,  7213,  7219,  7229,  7237,  7243,  7247,  7253,  7283,  7297,
   7307,  7309,  7321,  7331,  7333,  7349,  7351,  7369,  7393,  7411,
   7417,  7433,  7451,  7457,  7459,  7477,  7481,  7487,  7489,  7499,
   7507,  7517,  7523,  7529,  7537,  7541,  7547,  7549,  7559,  7561,
   7573,  7577,  7583,  7589,  7591,  7603,  7607,  7621,  7639,  7643,
   7649,  7669,  7673,  7681,  7687,  7691,  7699,  7703,  7717,  7723,
   7727,  7741,  7753,  7757,  7759,  7789,  7793,  7817,  7823,  7829,
   7841,  7853,  7867,  7873,  7877,  7879,  7883,  7901,  7907,  7919,
   7927,  7933,  7937,  7949,  7951,  7963,  7993,  8009,  8011,  8017,
   8039,  8053,  8059,  8069,  8081,  8087,  8089,  8093,  8101,  8111,
   8117,  8123,  8147,  8161,  8167,  8171,  8179,  8191,  8209,  8219,
   8221,  8231,  8233,  8237,  8243,  8263,  8269,  8273,  8287,  8291,
   8293,  8297,  8311,  8317,  8329,  8353,  8363,  8369,  8377,  8387,
   8389,  8419,  8423,  8429,  8431,  8443,  8447,  8461,  8467,  8501,
   8513,  8521,  8527,  8537,  8539,  8543,  8563,  8573,  8581,  8597,
   8599,  8609,  8623,  8627,  8629,  8641,  8647,  8663,  8669,  8677,
   8681,  8689,  8693,  8699,  8707,  8713,  8719,  8731,  8737,  8741,
   8747,  8753,  8761,  8779,  8783,  8803,  8807,  8819,  8821,  8831,
   8837,  8839,  8849,  8861,  8863,  8867,  8887,  8893,  8923,  8929,
   8933,  8941,  8951,  8963,  8969,  8971,  8999,  9001,  9007,  9011,
   9013,  9029,  9041,  9043,  9049,  9059,  9067,  9091,  9103,  9109,
   9127,  9133,  9137,  9151,  9157,  9161,  9173,  9181,  9187,  9199,
   9203,  9209,  9221,  9227,  9239,  9241,  9257,  9277,  9281,  9283,
   9293,  9311,  9319,  9323,  9337,  9341,  9343,  9349,  9371,  9377,
   9391,  9397,  9403,  9413,  9419,  9421,  9431,  9433,  9437,  9439,
   9461,  9463,  9467,  9473,  9479,  9491,  9497,  9511,  9521,  9533,
   9539,  9547,  9551,  9587,  9601,  9613,  9619,  9623,  9629,  9631,
   9643,  9649,  9661,  9677,  9679,  9689,  9697,  9719,  9721,  9733,
   9739,  9743,  9749,  9767,  9769,  9781,  9787,  9791,  9803,  9811,
   9817,  9829,  9833,  9839,  9851,  9857,  9859,  9871,  9883,  9887,
   9901,  9907,  9923,  9929,  9931,  9941,  9949,  9967,  9973, 10007,
  10009, 10037, 10039, 10061, 10067, 10069, 10079, 10091, 10093, 10099,
  10103, 10111, 10133, 10139, 10141, 10151, 10159, 10163, 10169, 10177,
  10181, 10193, 10211, 10223, 10243, 10247, 10253, 10259, 10267, 10271,
  10273, 10289, 10301, 10303, 10313, 10321, 10331, 10333, 10337, 10343,
  10357, 10369, 10391, 10399, 10427, 10429, 10433, 10453, 10457, 10459,
  10463, 10477, 10487, 10499, 10501, 10513, 10529, 10531, 10559, 10567,
  10589, 10597, 10601, 10607, 10613, 10627, 10631, 10639, 10651, 10657,
  10663, 10667, 10687, 10691, 10709, 10711, 10723, 10729, 10733, 10739,
  10753, 10771, 10781, 10789, 10799, 10831, 10837, 10847, 10853, 10859,
  10861, 10867, 10883, 10889, 10891, 10903, 10909, 10937, 10939, 10949,
  10957, 10973, 10979, 10987, 10993, 11003, 11027, 11047, 11057, 11059,
  11069, 11071, 11083, 11087, 11093, 11113, 11117, 11119, 11131, 11149,
  11159, 11161, 11171, 11173, 11177, 11197, 11213, 11239, 11243, 11251,
  11257, 11261, 11273, 11279, 11287, 11299, 11311, 11317, 11321, 11329,
  11351, 11353, 11369, 11383, 11393, 11399, 11411, 11423, 11437, 11443,
  11447, 11467, 11471, 11483, 11489, 11491, 11497, 11503, 11519, 11527,
  11549, 11551, 11579, 11587, 11593, 11597, 11617, 11621, 11633, 11657,
  11677, 11681, 11689, 11699, 11701, 11717, 11719, 11731, 11743, 11777,
  11779, 11783, 11789, 11801, 11807, 11813, 11821, 11827, 11831, 11833,
  11839, 11863, 11867, 11887, 11897, 11903, 11909, 11923, 11927, 11933,
  11939, 11941, 11953, 11959, 11969, 11971, 11981, 11987, 12007, 12011,
  12037, 12041, 12043, 12049, 12071, 12073, 12097, 12101, 12107, 12109,
  12113, 12119, 12143, 12149, 12157, 12161, 12163, 12197, 12203, 12211,
  12227, 12239, 12241, 12251, 12253, 12263, 12269, 12277, 12281, 12289,
  12301, 12323, 12329, 12343, 12347, 12373, 12377, 12379, 12391, 12401,
  12409, 12413, 12421, 12433, 12437, 12451, 12457, 12473, 12479, 12487,
  12491, 12497, 12503, 12511, 12517, 12527, 12539, 12541, 12547, 12553,
  12569, 12577, 12583, 12589, 12601, 12611, 12613, 12619, 12637, 12641,
  12647, 12653, 12659, 12671, 12689, 12697, 12703, 12713, 12721, 12739,
  12743, 12757, 12763, 12781, 12791, 12799, 12809, 12821, 12823, 12829,
  12841, 12853, 12889, 12893, 12899, 12907, 12911, 12917, 12919, 12923,
  12941, 12953, 12959, 12967, 12973, 12979, 12983, 13001, 13003, 13007,
  13009, 13033, 13037, 13043, 13049, 13063, 13093, 13099, 13103, 13109,
  13121, 13127, 13147, 13151, 13159, 13163, 13171, 13177, 13183, 13187,
  13217, 13219, 13229, 13241, 13249, 13259, 13267, 13291, 13297, 13309,
  13313, 13327, 13331, 13337, 13339, 13367, 13381, 13397, 13399, 13411,
  13417, 13421, 13441, 13451, 13457, 13463, 13469, 13477, 13487, 13499,
  13513, 13523, 13537, 13553, 13567, 13577, 13591, 13597, 13613, 13619,
  13627, 13633, 13649, 13669, 13679, 13681, 13687, 13691, 13693, 13697,
  13709, 13711, 13721, 13723, 13729, 13751, 13757, 13759, 13763, 13781,
  13789, 13799, 13807, 13829, 13831, 13841, 13859, 13873, 13877, 13879,
  13883, 13901, 13903, 13907, 13913, 13921, 13931, 13933, 13963, 13967,
  13997, 13999, 14009, 14011, 14029, 14033, 14051, 14057, 14071, 14081,
  14083, 14087, 14107, 14143, 14149, 14153, 14159, 14173, 14177, 14197,
  14207, 14221, 14243, 14249, 14251, 14281, 14293, 14303, 14321, 14323,
  14327, 14341, 14347, 14369, 14387, 14389, 14401, 14407, 14411, 14419,
  14423, 14431, 14437, 14447, 14449, 14461, 14479, 14489, 14503, 14519,
  14533, 14537, 14543, 14549, 14551, 14557, 14561, 14563, 14591, 14593,
  14621, 14627, 14629, 14633, 14639, 14653, 14657, 14669, 14683, 14699,
  14713, 14717, 14723, 14731, 14737, 14741, 14747, 14753, 14759, 14767,
  14771, 14779, 14783, 14797, 14813, 14821, 14827, 14831, 14843, 14851,
  14867, 14869, 14879, 14887, 14891, 14897, 14923, 14929, 14939, 14947,
  14951, 14957, 14969, 14983, 15013, 15017, 15031, 15053, 15061, 15073,
  15077, 15083, 15091, 15101, 15107, 15121, 15131, 15137, 15139, 15149,
  15161, 15173, 15187, 15193, 15199, 15217, 15227, 15233, 15241, 15259,
  15263, 15269, 15271, 15277, 15287, 15289, 15299, 15307, 15313, 15319,
  15329, 15331, 15349, 15359, 15361, 15373, 15377, 15383, 15391, 15401,
  15413, 15427, 15439, 15443, 15451, 15461, 15467, 15473, 15493, 15497,
  15511, 15527, 15541, 15551, 15559, 15569, 15581, 15583, 15601, 15607,
  15619, 15629, 15641, 15643, 15647, 15649, 15661, 15667, 15671, 15679,
  15683, 15727, 15731, 15733, 15737, 15739, 15749, 15761, 15767, 15773,
  15787, 15791, 15797, 15803, 15809, 15817, 15823, 15859, 15877, 15881,
  15887, 15889, 15901, 15907, 15913, 15919, 15923, 15937, 15959, 15971,
  15973, 15991, 16001, 16007, 16033, 16057, 16061, 16063, 16067, 16069,
  16073, 16087, 16091, 16097, 16103, 16111, 16127, 16139, 16141, 16183,
  16187, 16189, 16193, 16217, 16223, 16229, 16231, 16249, 16253, 16267,
  16273, 16301, 16319, 16333, 16339, 16349, 16361, 16363, 16369, 16381,
  16411, 16417, 16421, 16427, 16433, 16447, 16451, 16453, 16477, 16481,
  16487, 16493, 16519, 16529, 16547, 16553, 16561, 16567, 16573, 16603,
  16607, 16619, 16631, 16633, 16649, 16651, 16657, 16661, 16673, 16691,
  16693, 16699, 16703, 16729, 16741, 16747, 16759, 16763, 16787, 16811,
  16823, 16829, 16831, 16843, 16871, 16879, 16883, 16889, 16901, 16903,
  16921, 16927, 16931, 16937, 16943, 16963, 16979, 16981, 16987, 16993,
  17011, 17021, 17027, 17029, 17033, 17041, 17047, 17053, 17077, 17093,
  17099, 17107, 17117, 17123, 17137, 17159, 17167, 17183, 17189, 17191,
  17203, 17207, 17209, 17231, 17239, 17257, 17291, 17293, 17299, 17317,
  17321, 17327, 17333, 17341, 17351, 17359, 17377, 17383, 17387, 17389,
  17393, 17401, 17417, 17419, 17431, 17443, 17449, 17467, 17471, 17477,
  17483, 17489, 17491, 17497, 17509, 17519, 17539, 17551, 17569, 17573,
  17579, 17581, 17597, 17599, 17609, 17623, 17627, 17657, 17659, 17669,
  17681, 17683, 17707, 17713, 17729, 17737, 17747, 17749, 17761, 17783,
  17789, 17791, 17807, 17827, 17837, 17839, 17851, 17863, 17881, 17891,
  17903, 17909, 17911, 17921, 17923, 17929, 17939, 17957, 17959, 17971,
  17977, 17981, 17987, 17989, 18013, 18041, 18043, 18047, 18049, 18059,
  18061, 18077, 18089, 18097, 18119, 18121, 18127, 18131, 18133, 18143,
  18149, 18169, 18181, 18191, 18199, 18211, 18217, 18223, 18229, 18233,
  18251, 18253, 18257, 18269, 18287, 18289, 18301, 18307, 18311, 18313,
  18329, 18341, 18353, 18367, 18371, 18379, 18397, 18401, 18413, 18427,
  18433, 18439, 18443, 18451, 18457, 18461, 18481, 18493, 18503, 18517,
  18521, 18523, 18539, 18541, 18553, 18583, 18587, 18593, 18617, 18637,
  18661, 18671, 18679, 18691, 18701, 18713, 18719, 18731, 18743, 18749,
  18757, 18773, 18787, 18793, 18797, 18803, 18839, 18859, 18869, 18899,
  18911, 18913, 18917, 18919, 18947, 18959, 18973, 18979, 19001, 19009,
  19013, 19031, 19037, 19051, 19069, 19073, 19079, 19081, 19087, 19121,
  19139, 19141, 19157, 19163, 19181, 19183, 19207, 19211, 19213, 19219,
  19231, 19237, 19249, 19259, 19267, 19273, 19289, 19301, 19309, 19319,
  19333, 19373, 19379, 19381, 19387, 19391, 19403, 19417, 19421, 19423,
  19427, 19429, 19433, 19441, 19447, 19457, 19463, 19469, 19471, 19477,
  19483, 19489, 19501, 19507, 19531, 19541, 19543, 19553, 19559, 19571,
  19577, 19583, 19597, 19603, 19609, 19661, 19681, 19687, 19697, 19699,
  19709, 19717, 19727, 19739, 19751, 19753, 19759, 19763, 19777, 19793,
  19801, 19813, 19819, 19841, 19843, 19853, 19861, 19867, 19889, 19891,
  19913, 19919, 19927, 19937, 19949, 19961, 19963, 19973, 19979, 19991,
  19993, 19997, 20011, 20021, 20023, 20029, 20047, 20051, 20063, 20071,
  20089, 20101, 20107, 20113, 20117, 20123, 20129, 20143, 20147, 20149,
  20161, 20173, 20177, 20183, 20201, 20219, 20231, 20233, 20249, 20261,
  20269, 20287, 20297, 20323, 20327, 20333, 20341, 20347, 20353, 20357,
  20359, 20369, 20389, 20393, 20399, 20407, 20411, 20431, 20441, 20443,
  20477, 20479, 20483, 20507, 20509, 20521, 20533, 20543, 20549, 20551,
  20563, 20593, 20599, 20611, 20627, 20639, 20641, 20663, 20681, 20693,
  20707, 20717, 20719, 20731, 20743, 20747, 20749, 20753, 20759, 20771,
  20773, 20789, 20807, 20809, 20849, 20857, 20873, 20879, 20887, 20897,
  20899, 20903, 20921, 20929, 20939, 20947, 20959, 20963, 20981, 20983,
  21001, 21011, 21013, 21017, 21019, 21023, 21031, 21059, 21061, 21067,
  21089, 21101, 21107, 21121, 21139, 21143, 21149, 21157, 21163, 21169,
  21179, 21187, 21191, 21193, 21211, 21221, 21227, 21247, 21269, 21277,
  21283, 21313, 21317, 21319, 21323, 21341, 21347, 21377, 21379, 21383,
  21391, 21397, 21401, 21407, 21419, 21433, 21467, 21481, 21487, 21491,
  21493, 21499, 21503, 21517, 21521, 21523, 21529, 21557, 21559, 21563,
  21569, 21577, 21587, 21589, 21599, 21601, 21611, 21613, 21617, 21647,
  21649, 21661, 21673, 21683, 21701, 21713, 21727, 21737, 21739, 21751,
  21757, 21767, 21773, 21787, 21799, 21803, 21817, 21821, 21839, 21841,
  21851, 21859, 21863, 21871, 21881, 21893, 21911, 21929, 21937, 21943,
  21961, 21977, 21991, 21997, 22003, 22013, 22027, 22031, 22037, 22039,
  22051, 22063, 22067, 22073, 22079, 22091, 22093, 22109, 22111, 22123,
  22129, 22133, 22147, 22153, 22157, 22159, 22171, 22189, 22193, 22229,
  22247, 22259, 22271, 22273, 22277, 22279, 22283, 22291, 22303, 22307,
  22343, 22349, 22367, 22369, 22381, 22391, 22397, 22409, 22433, 22441,
  22447, 22453, 22469, 22481, 22483, 22501, 22511, 22531, 22541, 22543,
  22549, 22567, 22571, 22573, 22613, 22619, 22621, 22637, 22639, 22643,
  22651, 22669, 22679, 22691, 22697, 22699, 22709, 22717, 22721, 22727,
  22739, 22741, 22751, 22769, 22777, 22783, 22787, 22807, 22811, 22817,
  22853, 22859, 22861, 22871, 22877, 22901, 22907, 22921, 22937, 22943,
  22961, 22963, 22973, 22993, 23003, 23011, 23017, 23021, 23027, 23029,
  23039, 23041, 23053, 23057, 23059, 23063, 23071, 23081, 23087, 23099,
  23117, 23131, 23143, 23159, 23167, 23173, 23189, 23197, 23201, 23203,
  23209, 23227, 23251, 23269, 23279, 23291, 23293, 23297, 23311, 23321,
  23327, 23333, 23339, 23357, 23369, 23371, 23399, 23417, 23431, 23447,
  23459, 23473, 23497, 23509, 23531, 23537, 23539, 23549, 23557, 23561,
  23563, 23567, 23581, 23593, 23599, 23603, 23609, 23623, 23627, 23629,
  23633, 23663, 23669, 23671, 23677, 23687, 23689, 23719, 23741, 23743,
  23747, 23753, 23761, 23767, 23773, 23789, 23801, 23813, 23819, 23827,
  23831, 23833, 23857, 23869, 23873, 23879, 23887, 23893, 23899, 23909,
  23911, 23917, 23929, 23957, 23971, 23977, 23981, 23993, 24001, 24007,
  24019, 24023, 24029, 24043, 24049, 24061, 24071, 24077, 24083, 24091,
  24097, 24103, 24107, 24109, 24113, 24121, 24133, 24137, 24151, 24169,
  24179, 24181, 24197, 24203, 24223, 24229, 24239, 24247, 24251, 24281,
  24317, 24329, 24337, 24359, 24371, 24373, 24379, 24391, 24407, 24413,
  24419, 24421, 24439, 24443, 24469, 24473, 24481, 24499, 24509, 24517,
  24527, 24533, 24547, 24551, 24571, 24593, 24611, 24623, 24631, 24659,
  24671, 24677, 24683, 24691, 24697, 24709, 24733, 24749, 24763, 24767,
  24781, 24793, 24799, 24809, 24821, 24841, 24847, 24851, 24859, 24877,
  24889, 24907, 24917, 24919, 24923, 24943, 24953, 24967, 24971, 24977,
  24979, 24989, 25013
]
```

Here is my recursive routine that finds all combinations of distinct prime numbers whose product is less than a given number. This code is rather pythonic--let me know if you need help converting this to another language. I programmed this some time ago for another problem, so you do not need two of the four items returned for each combination--you need only the product of the primes and the marker `mu` whether to add or subtract for this combination.

```
def prime_combinations(n):
    """Generate combinations of distinct primes where their product is
    less than n. Each yielded item is a 4-tuple containing:
    - the combination in increasing order,
    - k where the last and largest prime in the combination is the k'th
      prime (where 2 is the 1st prime),
    - the product of the primes in the combination,
    - the Moebius mu function of the product (i.e. 1 if the combination
      has an even number of primes, -1 if an odd number of primes).
    Items are yielded in lexicographical order. The first item yielded
    is the empty combination ((), 0, 1, 1).
    """

    def primecombos(prefix, ndx, prod, mu):
        yield prefix, ndx, prod, mu
        while True:
            newprime = primes_2_25000[ndx]
            newprod = prod * newprime
            if newprod >= n:
                return
            ndx += 1
            yield from primecombos(prefix + (newprime,), ndx, newprod, -mu)

    if 1 < n <= primes_2_25000[-1] and n == int(n):
        yield from primecombos((), 0, 1, 1)
```

Given those things, the code that solves your problem is quite short:

```
def relatively_prime_quadruplets(n):
    result = 0
    for _, _, prime_prod, mu in prime_combinations(n // 4 + 1):
        cnt = n // prime_prod
        result += mu * cnt * (cnt - 1) * (cnt - 2) * (cnt - 3) // 24
    return result
```

Put all those in one module and you have your solution. I tested this code for all values `n` from `4` through `100` by comparing with a brute-force solution. I stopped at `100` because the brute-force routine had become slow (`4.07` seconds). My code is much faster: for `100` it runs in `23.5` microseconds. For your maximum value `100000` it runs in `23.1` milliseconds. That seems to be linear execution complexity, what I had expected.

Here's the test code if you need it:

```
import functools
import math 
import itertools

def gcd_iter(iterable):
    """Return the greatest common divisor of the numbers in an
    iterable."""
    return functools.reduce(math.gcd, iterable, 0)

def brute(n):
    return sum(1 for c in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), 4) if gcd_iter(c) == 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range(4, 101):
        print(n, relatively_prime_quadruplets(n) == brute(n))
```